# Problemas con condición de un bucle while

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una actividad que se trata de un laberinto y el jugador debe encontrar la salida. La posición inicial se marca con una **J** y, a medida que el usuario se mueve, la posición de la **J** varía y se reemplaza por un **0** para ir marcando el camino que el usuario ha seguido.
El ejercicio lo resuelvo usando un array del tipo **String** que contiene lo que sería el laberinto físico y otro array del tipo **boolean** se se encarga de indicar qué posiciones del array anterior se muestran o no.

Como se ve en el código que hay a continuación, el juego se va ejecutando mientras que las coordenadas del jugador `currentX`y `currentY`sean distintas a las coordenadas que marcan el final del laberinto que son **27** y **9**. El caso es que cuando una de las coordenadas X o Y coincide con una de las coordenadas que marcan el final del laberinto el juego se termina y no debería ser así. Me explico, si las coordenadas del jugador son **27** y **8** (coincide la coordenada 27) o **26** y **9** (coincide la coordenada 9) el juego se finaliza y solo debería hacerlo con las coordenadas indicadas en el bucle `while`

Clase que llama al resto del código:

```
package laberint;


public class init {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        laberint joc = new laberint();


        joc.beginGame();

    }

}
```

Resto del código:

```
package laberint;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class laberint {
    static final int ROW = 10;
    static final int COL = 30;
    int currentX = 2, currentY = 4; // 2 - 4 
    int counter = 0;        

    Scanner intro = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean [][] checkWhereIsVisible = new boolean [][]{
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,true ,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
        {false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false},
    };
    String [][] table = new String[][]{
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","0","0","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","#","#","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","0","0","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","#","#","0","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","J","#","0","#","#","#","0","0","0","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","0","0","0","0","0","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","0","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","0","0","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","#","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","0","0","0","#","#","#","0","0","0","0","0","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","0","0","0","0","0","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","#","#"},
        {"#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","0","#","#"},
    };


    public void beginGame(){    
        while((currentX != 27) && (currentY != 9)){
            showVisibleField(table, checkWhereIsVisible);
            String userDirection = askDirection();
            counter++;
            checkNextPosition(currentX, currentY, userDirection, table);
        }
        System.out.println("Has guanyat!\nMoviments realitzats: " + counter);
        System.out.println("X " + currentX);
        System.out.println("Y " + currentY);
    }

    private void showVisibleField(String[][] table, boolean[][] booleanTable){ // OK
        int i = 0, a = 0;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(a=0;a<30;a++){
                if(booleanTable[i][a]){ // --------- posicion en la tabla = true    
                    System.out.print(" " + table[i][a] + " ");
                }else{ // --------- posicion en la tabla = false
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private String askDirection(){ // OK
        String answer = "";
        Scanner intro = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("w") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("s") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("a") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
            System.out.println("Introdueix la seguent direccio [w/s/a/d]");
            answer = intro.next();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private boolean checkNextPosition(int currentX, int currentY, String userDirection, String[][] table){
        int auxX = currentX;
        int auxY = currentY;
        boolean booleanCheckNextPosition = false;
        if(userDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
            auxY = auxY - 1;
        }else if(userDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            auxY = auxY + 1;
        }else if(userDirection.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
            auxX = auxX - 1;
        }else{ // d
            auxX = auxX + 1;
        }
        if(checkSimulatedMovement(auxX, auxY, table)){
            setCellVisible(auxX, auxY, table,checkWhereIsVisible);
            booleanCheckNextPosition = true;
        }else{
            booleanCheckNextPosition = false;
        }
        return booleanCheckNextPosition;


    }

    private boolean checkSimulatedMovement(int auxX, int auxY, String[][] table){ // fem una simulacio del que seria el moviment del jugador per veure si seria possible realitzar-lo

        boolean returnIfIsValid = false;
        if(auxX >= 0 && auxX < 30 && auxY >= 0 && auxY <10){            
            if(table[auxY][auxX].equalsIgnoreCase("#")){
                setWallVisible(auxX, auxY);
                System.out.println(table[auxY][auxX]);
                returnIfIsValid = false;
            }else if(table[auxY][auxX].equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                System.out.println(table[auxY][auxX]);
                returnIfIsValid = true;
            }else{

            }
        }else{
            returnIfIsValid = false;
        }       
        return returnIfIsValid;

    }

    private void setCellVisible(int auxX, int auxY, String[][] table, boolean[][] checkWhereIsVisible){
        checkWhereIsVisible[auxY][auxX] = true;
        movePlayer(auxY, auxX);
    }

    private void movePlayer(int auxY, int auxX){
        table[auxY][auxX] = "J";
        table[currentY][currentX] = "0";
        currentX = auxX;
        currentY = auxY;    
    }

    private void setWallVisible(int auxX, int auxY){
        checkWhereIsVisible[auxY][auxX] = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es que esta mal la logica de tu condicion de iteracion..

Estas iterando mientras X sea distinto de 27 y Y sea distinto de 9...

si uno de los dos falla, entonces dejas de iterar..

fijate X=26 Y=9

```
(currentX != 27) && (currentY != 9)
(26 != 27) && (9 != 9)
    T      &&    F
           F (sale del while)
```

Lo que vos queres hacer es iterar mientras esos dos valores sean distintos de 27 y 9, eso es correcto, pero mientras pase eso, debes iterar!

Entonces tu condicion deberia ser un or.. o sea, mientras alguno de los valores sea diferente, seguir en el `WHILE`

```
(currentX != 27) || (currentY != 9)
(26 != 27) && (9 != 9)
    T      &&    F
           T
```

Si x=27 e Y=9

```
(currentX != 27) || (currentY != 9)
(27 != 27) && (9 != 9)
    F      &&    F
           F
```